# Adding key listener to my jframe not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to add key inputs to my game, and just can't figure this out. I've watched a handful of tutorials and have my friend also trying to find this out, but we've both failed to see whats wrong.
This class is part of project with 6 other classes. None of those effect this class besides it getting passed over an array over from another class. I'm a noob to programming so forgive me if it's obvious what's wrong!

Edit: I've successfully added the listener to the JFrame, its now at the bottom of the renderWorld method. My new problem is that everytime I click on any of the buttons, the listener stops working. This seems to have something to do with the setting of focus. I've done some testing and found if I remove the loop that adds buttons to the screen, so it only adds a black panel, it works just fine.

public class DisplayWorld extends JFrame{

```
int[][] displayWorld;//create loaded world array for this class

boolean inializedVariables = false;

/*
 * ***********************
 * */

int tileSize;
int x;
int y;

int buttonsPrinted;
int counter;
int[] playerStartLocation = {0, 0};
int xCord;
int yCord;
int cullX;
int cullY;
int finished;

JFrame window;
Dimension screenSize;
JPanel panel;

Icon iconDirt;
Icon iconGrassForest;
Icon iconWater;
Icon iconPlayer;

public DisplayWorld(int[][] loadedWorld) {
    this.displayWorld = loadedWorld;
}

public void initializeVariables() {
    tileSize = 80;
    x = -(tileSize * 25);
    y = -(tileSize * 25);
    buttonsPrinted = 0;
    counter = 0;
    playerStartLocation[0] = displayWorld.length / 2;
    playerStartLocation[1] = displayWorld.length / 2;
    xCord = playerStartLocation[0]; 
    yCord = playerStartLocation[1];
    cullX = 100;
    cullY = 100;
    finished = (cullX) * (cullY);

    window = new JFrame();
    window.setLayout(null);
    window.setLocation(0, 0);

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    window.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setVisible(true);

    iconDirt = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chris\\IdeaProjects\\Lovecraft Game\\src\\resources\\dirt.png");
    iconGrassForest = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chris\\IdeaProjects\\Lovecraft Game\\src\\resources\\grassForest.png");
    iconWater = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chris\\IdeaProjects\\Lovecraft Game\\src\\resources\\water.png");
    iconPlayer = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\chris\\IdeaProjects\\Lovecraft Game\\src\\resources\\player.png");

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);


        }


public void renderWorld() throws InterruptedException { 

    if (!inializedVariables) {
        initializeVariables();
        inializedVariables = true;
    }

    while (finished > counter) { //loop to put buttons on screen

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setName(xCord + "," + yCord);
        button.setBounds(x = x + tileSize, y, tileSize, tileSize);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        button.setIcon(iconDirt);

        if (displayWorld[xCord][yCord] == 1) {
            button.setIcon(iconGrassForest);
        }
        if (displayWorld[xCord][yCord] == 2) {
            button.setIcon(iconWater);
        }

        class buttonPressed implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                String buttonReport = button.getName();
                String[] returnedCords = buttonReport.split(",");
                int tileReturnedX = Integer.parseInt(returnedCords[0]);
                int tileReturnedY = Integer.parseInt(returnedCords[1]);
                System.out.println(tileReturnedX);
                System.out.println(tileReturnedY);
            }
        }

        button.addActionListener(new buttonPressed());
        panel.add(button);
        counter++;
        buttonsPrinted++;
        xCord++;

        if (buttonsPrinted == cullX) {
            y = y + tileSize;
            yCord++;
            buttonsPrinted = 0;
            x = tileSize - tileSize - tileSize;
            xCord = playerStartLocation[0];
        }
    }
    window.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {


        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    System.out.println("reeee");
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

    });

    panel.setBounds(0, 0, tileSize * cullX, tileSize * cullY);
    window.getContentPane().add(panel);
    System.out.println("Render Updated");
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you put print statements in each of the methods of the KeyListener. It would be best if you identified where the print statements were, like: System.out.println("keyPressed: " + e.getKeyCode());

Comment: That doesn't work either